# search items based on dropdown selection in angular 4

Tags: angular

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private userService: PostGetService, 
    private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoryId = this._Activatedroute.snapshot.params['categoryId'];
    this.userService.searchListingById(Number(this.categoryId))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.rawdata = res.json();
        console.log(this.rawdata)
      });
  }
}
```

I have a dropdown menu where I will select a category and based on that category I want to display its related data on another page

I have a response like this i.e. I need to display these details on next page

```
[{
  "id": 45,
  "installerTitle": "Test112",
  "firstName": "Test112",
  "middleName": "Test112",
  "lastName": "Test112",
  "emailId": "Test112",
  "contactNo": "Test112",
  "password": "Test112",
  "installerType": "Test112",
  "keywords": "Test112",
  "status": "Test112",
  "isActive": 2,
  "desc": null,
  "installerlocation": [{
    "installerLocationId": 12,
    "addresslineOne": "Test112",
    "addresslineTwo": "Test112",
    "addresslineThree": "Test112",
    "city": "Test112",
    "state": "Test112",
    "zipcode": "Test112",
    "gecodeX": 2,
    "gecodeY": 2,
    "isActive": 2,
    "status": "Test112"
  }],
  "installerPayment": [{
      "installerPaymentId": 16,
      "installerStripeId": "cus_DdJsIWh9ake0Bc",
      "installerAmt": null,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "installerPaymentId": 16,
      "installerStripeId": "cus_DdJsIWh9ake0Bc",
      "installerAmt": null,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "installerPaymentId": 16,
      "installerStripeId": "cus_DdJsIWh9ake0Bc",
      "installerAmt": null,
      "status": 1
    }
  ],
  "installersocial": [{
    "installerSocialId": 11,
    "socialType": "Test112",
    "socialUrl": "Test112",
    "facebookUrl": "Test112",
    "twitterUrl": "Test112",
    "vkontakeUrl": "Test112",
    "whatsappUrl": "Test112"
  }],
  "installerworktiming": [{
    "installerTimeId": 12,
    "locationId": 2,
    "dayId": 2,
    "timeFrom": 2,
    "timeTo": 2,
    "isHoliday": 2,
    "timeSunday": "Test112",
    "timeMonday": "Test112",
    "timeTuesday": "Test112",
    "timeWednesday": "Test112",
    "timeThursday": "Test112",
    "timeFriday": "Test112",
    "timeSaturday": "Test112"
  }],
  "installerserviceModel": [{
      "installerServiceId": 13,
      "category": {
        "categoryId": 35,
        "categoryName": "Test101",
        "categoryDesc": "Test101",
        "categoryServicemodel": [{
          "serviceId": 8,
          "serviceName": "Test101",
          "serviceDesc": "Test101",
          "isActive": 1
        }],
        "active": 1
      },
      "categoryServiceModel": {
        "serviceId": 8,
        "serviceName": "Test101",
        "serviceDesc": "Test101",
        "isActive": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "installerServiceId": 12,
      "category": {
        "categoryId": 17,
        "categoryName": "Test98",
        "categoryDesc": "Test98",
        "categoryServicemodel": [{
            "serviceId": 7,
            "serviceName": "Test98",
            "serviceDesc": "Test98",
            "isActive": 8
          },
          {
            "serviceId": 13,
            "serviceName": "Test115",
            "serviceDesc": "Test115",
            "isActive": 1
          }
        ],
        "active": 8
      },
      "categoryServiceModel": {
        "serviceId": 7,
        "serviceName": "Test98",
        "serviceDesc": "Test98",
        "isActive": 8
      }
    },
    {
      "installerServiceId": 11,
      "category": {
        "categoryId": 7,
        "categoryName": "Test Name",
        "categoryDesc": "Test Description",
        "categoryServicemodel": [{
          "serviceId": 6,
          "serviceName": "serv name test",
          "serviceDesc": "serv desc test",
          "isActive": 1
        }],
        "active": 0
      },
      "categoryServiceModel": {
        "serviceId": 6,
        "serviceName": "serv name test",
        "serviceDesc": "serv desc test",
        "isActive": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

These are the details I want to get on one of the category id selection I don't want to display all details on few details that is name, email, contact number.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Are you not getting the updated `categoryId` in your Component? I think that's the problem. And that's because you didn't `subscribe` to  `this._Activatedroute.params` and instead used `this._Activatedroute.snapshot.params`

Comment: no i am getting the data but whats my issue is when i clicked on search all details will come  my issue is how to bind this dropdown value to search button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first i created service in service.ts file

```
 searchListingById(categoryId: number): Observable<any> {

 if(categoryId == 0 || categoryId == undefined){
   return this.getListings().delay(100)
  }else{
   return this.http.get( this.searchCatUrl+categoryId).delay(100);
  }
}
```

> from here i am passing selected dropdown id  to search based on that selected id 
>     .... then i am calling above service method from my component.ts file

```
 this.userService.searchListingById(this.categoryId)
     .subscribe(res => {              
        this.categoryRawdata = res.json();             
       });
```

> and values will be stored in categoryRawdata variable and in component.html bind values using this variable